# How to copy cell if equals value, otherwise, do nothing?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set that used to format as

```
Row 1: 0/0
Row 2: 2/3
Row 3: 0/0
Row 4: 1/2
```

I created the below to copy the value from the row below to replace the "0/0"

```
Sub SOIROM() 'this macro copies the SOI/ROM from the APR-DRG line and pastes it on the MS-DRG line
Dim lr As Long
Dim rcell As Range
Dim col As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

Set col = Range("M2:M" & lr)

    For Each rcell In col

        If rcell.Value = "0/0" Then

        rcell.Offset(1, 0).Copy rcell

        End If

    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

However, now the source file does not follow a predicted format (each two lines of data are for one account, used to be that all first lines are 0/0 then the following line are the true values.)

Now it's more like

```
Row 1: 1/3
Row 2: 0/0
Row 3: 0/0
Row 4: 3/4
```

So, the VBA no longer works consistently. Each two lines of data correspond to one unique account. So in essence, I want to evaluate the first row in each account (two rows) and IF the value = "0/0" then copy the cell from below, however, if the cell value = anything other than "0/0" I want to do nothing and leave the value as is (1/4, or whatever.)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what results do you now expect?

Comment: What used to happen is, the row that had the real value, I would copy the value (1/3, etc.) to the primary row, then delete the row with the real value. So, on the final product, that entire column would contain true results (1/2,3/4 etc.) and not be 0/0. However since the source file has changed, the final column now has a mixture of 0/0 and real values. I expect to get back to only real values, and, no more 0/0 values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for values that are not "0/0", then remove the offset and copy every cell that is not "0/0".

```
Sub SOIROM() 'this macro copies the SOI/ROM from the APR-DRG line and pastes it on the MS-DRG line
   Dim lr As Long
   Dim rcell As Range
   Dim col As Range

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

   Set col = Range("M2:M" & lr)
   For Each rcell In col
      If rcell.Value = "0/0" Then
         #rcell.Offset(1, 0).Copy rcell
         rcell.Copy rcell
      End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True  
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
Sub SOIROM() 'this macro copies the SOI/ROM from the APR-DRG line and pastes it on the MS-DRG line
Dim lr As Long
Dim rcell As Range
Dim col As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set col = Range("M2:M" & lr)
For Each rcell In col
    'If rcell.Value = "0/0" Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsErr(rcell) Then
        rcell.Offset(1, 0).Copy rcell
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately, the output data still contains a large amount of "0/0" values.

Comment: This is the same code, but you are seeing if the cell IsErr rather than looking for "0/0" like the OP was requesting. Not sure what error check does here.